# передвижение объекта вправо-влево с помощью тач скрин

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте!

Пытаюсь реализовать перемещение персонажа вправо влево как это реализовано в *Crossy Road*: если игрок двигает по экрану влево персонаж прыгает влево. Как это сделать?

Я сделала только вверх.

```
Input.simulateMouseWithTouches = true;
Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0);
if (grounded && (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0))) {
    rb.AddForce (new Vector2(0f, jumpForce));
}
```

Мне нужно движение персонажа вправо-влево.

Comment: Так всё же вам нужно движение влево-вправо в виде прыжка или просто перемещения? А то до кода у вас написано одно, после - другое. Не совсем ясно, что именно ожидается.......И не многие знают, что такое `Crossy Road`

Answer (score 0):

Что-то такое:

```
   Vector2 current;
   ...

    var pos = Input.mousePosition;

    if ( pos.x < current.x)
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(-jumpForce, 0f));
    else if(pos.x > current.x)
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(jumpForce, 0f));

    current = pos;
```

Хотя он скорее всего улетит за экран. Я б не так делал, но зависит от механики игры.

Comment: тут зависит от логики...ТС неразборчиво написал: нужно движение в виде прыжка или простое перемещение..... если именно прыжок в сторону, то это решение неверное по многим параметрам))

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, я тоже не знаю что тс хотел, потому написал ему хоть что-то для старта. А вообще, этот пример будет выглядеть не красиво, конечно, но это уже проблемы тс.

Comment: Не совсем так. Ведь это **база знаний**. Для всех. Поэтому желательно узнать, что же именно хотел ТС, а потом писать ответ. Причем который **поможет всем**.. Чтоб им **могли** воспользоваться и остальные, кто может зайти на ресурс. А ответы "на отвали" лучше не писать вовсе. Они никак не помогают